# Angular table of input and button

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with fields from `ng-repeat`. I have added two extra field such as a **input** and a **button** to each row.

What i want is when i enter some value in input and press button i want to run a function with the value of corresponding input. How do i do that?

My View

```
<tr ng-click="" ng-repeat='customer in customers | filter:query | orderBy: sort.field : sort.order'>

    <td ng-repeat='field in fields'>
        {{customer[field]}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" name="debit" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="genEcs(customer['id'])" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >ECS</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My controller

```
$scope.genEcs=function(id){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a model to your input via `ng-model` attribute. The model would be defined in the scope of each `customer` of `ng-repeat`, because `ng-repeat` creates child scopes:

So, you could do this:

```
<tr ng-repeat='customer in customers>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="customersDebit" name="debit" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="genEcs(customer, customersDebit)">ECS</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

(I also suggest, for the sake of readability and separation of concerns, to pass the entire `customer` object to the `genEcs` function, rather than only the `id` field. The less your View knows about business logic, the better.)